# Cannot get ElasticSearch to map all fields as text

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to map all fields as `text`. Based on the docs, this should work, but it doesn't:

```
PUT my_type
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "longs_as_strings": {
            "match_mapping_type": "*",
            "match":   "*",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

PUT my_type/my_type/1
{
  "intfield": 5
}

GET my_type/_search
```

Results in:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_type",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "intfield": 5
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you intentionally naming your index and mapping type same name `my_type`? this might be the issue. Also is `_all` insufficient in your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that ended up working:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "my_record": {
            "dynamic_templates": [{
                "longs_as_strings": {
                    "match_mapping_type": "*",
                    "match": "*",
                    "mapping": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only thing, that you changed - document type name (from `my_type` to` my_record`). Everything works the same as before. And like I said in my answer below - "ES index your data correctly". Because with new mapping, nothing has changed, except document type name.

Comment: I changed a lot more than just the type name. I needed a dynamic template to coerce all of the fields to be a text type.

Answer (score 0):

I think ES index your data correctly. Try to get mapping of your index, after document was added. Execute this:

```
GET my_type
```

I think you will get something like this:

```
{
    "my_type": {
        ...
        "mappings": {
            "my_type": {
                ...
                "properties": {
                    "intfield": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

As you see, ES index you `intfield` like text. And you could work with this field, like with text field.

When you try to get back your data, ES return data "as is". But in index, it store data like text